# How to block certain pages with a password

Tags: php, security, passwords

I want to create a simple thing to store my projects online, like a "Testing Host".

I already have done this: (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/display-styled-directory-contents/) and its pretty much what I want.

The only problem is, it's not password protected and everyone can see it. I want to block it to everyone without a password.

So I'm here looking for suggestions, tips, and useful functions to use and some bits of code to do it in the easiest yet the best way to achieve this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication is an easy way supported by many webservers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do this is adding an index file, make the index file password protected and when they are signed in they can see the content.

Answer (score 0):

Just Create a basic Login feature to our site.